# how to generate a blank option and clean a dropdown in angular

Tags: angular

What's up guys, I'm new at Angular and I have a doubt. I have a dropdown and I want to have a first blank element by default something like `"select an option"`, and when the user selects a dropdown element this first field disappears. later with the help of a `setInterval` I am trying to clean my dropdown to not select any option and to see the dropdown as I was from the beginning. How can I achieve it? This is my code.

```
<select  [(ngModel)]='myselect' >
  <option [value]="" selected  >select and option</option>
  <option  *ngFor='let option of test' [value]="option.id">  
 {{option.nombre}}</option>
</select>

  title = 'app';
  myselect:any;
  test:any= [{"id": "1", "nombre":"pedro" },{"id": "2", "nombre":"yeison" }];
  ngOnInit() {
    this.timeoutFun();
  }
  timeoutFun() {
    setTimeout(function(){
    //clear my dropdown 
    this.myselect=""; 
  }, 5000);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will do it:

```
  <select class="form-control"
          formControlName="frequency" [(ngModel)]="frequencies[i]">
     <option selected value></option>
     <option id="{'convertFromFrequencyDropDownOption'+i}" *ngFor="let frequency of (frequency$ | async)" [ngValue]="frequency">
              {{ getConcatenatedFrequency(frequency) }}
     </option>
  </select>
```

the key being:

```
<option selected value></option>
```

Comment: the first option is blank withouth text.. And I can chose that option in any moment..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<select  [(ngModel)]='myselect'>
  <option *ngIf="myselect==''" [value]="">select an option</option>
  <option  *ngFor='let option of test' [value]="option.id">  
 {{option.nombre}}</option>
</select>
```

And in ts:

```
  title = 'app';
  myselect:any = "";
  test:any= [{"id": "1", "nombre":"pedro" },{"id": "2", "nombre":"yeison" }];
  ngOnInit() {
    this.timeoutFun();
  }
  timeoutFun() {
    setTimeout(function(){
    this.myselect=""; 
  }, 5000);
 }
```

Comment: You could also use `[hidden]` instead of `*ngIf` if you want the option to not be removed from the DOM.

Comment: thanks.. but the first option has text in blank.. :(

Comment: @yavg I just realized now that you are calling function `timeoutFun()` in `ngOnInit()`. Doing that will only reset the field at the initialization of the component. If you want to start timeOut immediately after changing the value of the select field, you have to use `(change)` event to call the `this.timeoutFun()`. But still, I'm not clear why you want to reset the select field at the first place using setTimeout. It would be helpful if you could post a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:AvJOMERrnz94ekVua0u5?p=catalogue) to help better understand your code.

Comment: @yavg `but the first option has text in blank` I didn't get you... Can you explain when does that have text? Before changing value or after?